# Android HLS support using Media Codec, Media Extractor API

Tags: android

Hi I am writing a media player with the help of Media Codec and Media Extractor API. It is working fine, when I tested with some HTTP links. Then I tested it with HTTP live stream URL, it is not working.

ex: `"http://mediamotiononline.ios.internapcdn.net/mediamotiononline/inapcms/CMS16042/flash/16042_adaptive2.mp4.m3u8"`

I have tried to parse m3u8 file, but it is giving info of Bandwidth, resolution only. With VideoView widget these Http live stream URLs works fine. But I am using Surface to show decoded data. Anyone has any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might be help you.

- Download m3u8 parser from http://sourceforge.net/projects/m3u8parser/

  1. Add it to your project either jar file or source files.
  2. By using this parser you can get PlaylistInfo, elements.
  3. Explore for playable .ts files in elements. Pass those ts files to your MediaExtractor. It worked for me. Hope it will work for you
     too..